# Using an object as an instance variable in a basic Objective C program, I get an "expected specifier-qualifier-list" error

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I am writing a simple program that uses an object *center from an XYPoint class as an instance variable.

```
@interface Circle : NSObject {
    int radius;
    XYPoint *center;
}
```

however, I get this error message when compiling the code:

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'XYPoint'

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In Circle.h, you need to declare the XYPoint class:

```
@class XYPoint;
```

Then, in Circle.m, import its full definition:

```
#import "XYPoint.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the appropriate header file that defines the `XYPoint` class.

Comment: I disagree. Importing the XYPoint.h into Circle.h introduces an unnecessary dependency that will slow down build time. Better to declare it with @class, and put the #import in Circle.m.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley Indeed, @class would be more preferable, I agree.